# Reactjs - Add, Delete from arrays dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which takes input and adds them to a list and displays them:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {
    Form,
    Col,
    Label,
    FormGroup,
    Button,
    Alert,
    Input,
    Row,
} from 'reactstrap'

export default class NewSubreddit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {rules: []}
    }

    addRule() {
        const rule = document.getElementById('new-rule').value
        if(rule) {
            this.setState(prev => ({
                rules: prev.rules.concat(rule),
            }))
        }
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    deleteRule(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(e.target)
        // this.setState(prev => ({

        // }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Form>
                    <FormGroup row>
                        <Label sm={2}>Rules</Label>
                        <Col sm={10}>
                            <Row>
                                <Col>
                                    <Input id='new-rule' type='text' placeholder='Add a rule that members of this community should follow!'/>
                                </Col>
                                <Col>
                                    <Button onClick={() => this.addRule()}>ADD RULE</Button>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Col>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup row>
                        <Col>
                            {this.state.rules.map((rule) => 
                                <Alert key={rule} isOpen={true} toggle={this.deleteRule}>{rule}</Alert>
                            )}
                        </Col>
                    </FormGroup>
                </Form>   
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

So, I am able to add the rules to the array `rules` present in `state`.

There are 2 things that I need to do here:

- Restrict to create only fixed number of rules (say 4).
- Delete a Rule by toggling the alert.

I tried to do the deletion in `deleteRule` function by trying to access `event.target.value` but it is `undefined`!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create some const with max number of rules and update your addRule function

in the constructor you can add

```
this.maxNumberOfRules = 4;
```

then update

```
addRule() {
    const rule = document.getElementById('new-rule').value
    if(!rule || this.state.rules.length === this.maxNumberOfRules) {
        return null;
    }
    this.setState({rules: [...this.state.rules, rule]})
}
```

[...this.state.rules, rule] creates a new array with all items + new one.
Then you can pass the rule or index of rule for deletion

```
{this.state.rules.map((rule, index) => 
    <Alert key={rule} isOpen={true} toggle={(e) => this.deleteRule(e, index)}>{rule}</Alert>
 )}
```

and change

```
deleteRule(e, indexForDelete) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(index)
    this.setState({rules: this.state.rules.filter((rule, ruleIndex) => ruleIndex !== indexForDelete)})
}
```

The filter() method creates an array filled with all array elements that pass a test (provided as a function).

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the specific element by this method:

```
  deleteRule = (idx) => () => {
    this.setState({
        rules: this
            .state
            .rules
            .filter((s, sidx) => idx !== sidx)
    });
}
```

You have to call function as:

```
     <Col>
        {this.state.rules.map((rule,idx) => 
        <Alert key={rule} isOpen={true} toggle={this.deleteRule(idx)}>{rule} 
        </Alert>
         )}
      </Col>
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

You could create an inline function and pass in the index of the rule in the array to `deleteRule` instead of the event and remove that rule from your state.

You could also hide the add button when you have 4 or more rules in your state.

**Example**

```
class NewSubreddit extends Component {

  // ...

  deleteRule(ruleIndex) {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      const rules = [...previousState.rules];
      rules.splice(ruleIndex, 1);
      return { rules };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Form>
          <FormGroup row>
            <Label sm={2}>Rules</Label>
            <Col sm={10}>
              <Row>
                <Col>
                  <Input
                    id="new-rule"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Add a rule that members of this community should follow!"
                  />
                </Col>
                <Col>
                  {this.state.rules.length < 4 && (
                    <Button onClick={() => this.addRule()}>ADD RULE</Button>
                  )}
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Col>
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup row>
            <Col>
              {this.state.rules.map((rule, index) => (
                <Alert
                  key={rule}
                  isOpen={true}
                  toggle={() => this.deleteRule(index)}
                >
                  {rule}
                </Alert>
              ))}
            </Col>
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding delete function to close button and it doesn't have any value. Either you need to add the click event for "Col" or else you can pass rule as a parameter.

```
<Col>
  {this.state.rules.map((rule) => 
    <Alert key={rule} isOpen={true} toggle={() => this.deleteRule(rule)}>{rule}</Alert>
  )}
```

```
deleteRule(rule) {
    console.log(rule);
    // make a separate copy of the array
    var array = [...this.state.rules]; 
    var index = array.indexOf(rule);
    array.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({rules: array});
}
```

I created a simple stack app with your code in stackblitz, please have a look.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eqv744